# Performance implications filter/order/limit array in php (for+if) vs SQL clauses

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working with [wordpress](http://wordpress.org/), and it has a nice [database](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) [interface](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts), it is very useful to do a lot of somewhat simple queries.

I wanted to use this interface but it doesn't allow me to do some special filtering. Then I thought I could return a resultset from the database, and then make a filter using a php for with a nested if, taking out the results I did not want.

I was thinking on doing the same for ordering.

I know that if I have indices (in PHP I can't have them for arrays, but in mysql I have) operations like filter (WHERE) and ordering are super fast, comparing to sequential.

I was thinking on the performance that the php_mysql adapter has, I don't know if it uses something like lazy loading data, cursors, and the memory implications in passing data from the database to php.

Another use is in limiting/counting, in the common case of generating pagination links, where one needs the limited data, but also the total count. There are the two options to do that:

- using two queries: one for the count and one with the limit and actual data.
- using one query no limit, and counting the resulset in PHP

Does anyone knows what are the performance implication of doing this work in PHP vs. MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP is quite efficient dealing with some data structures, such as hashtables (regular arrays are treated as hashtables in php). What's not so efficient is accessing those structures in your code. Let me try to demonstrate that below.

Let's suppose you're iterating through all items in your array making a comparison and excluding items. I can think of two ways you can do it:

**Number 1:**

```
$arr = array_filter($arr2, function($item) { return $item > 2; });
```

`array_filter` in this case will basically iterate over all $arr2 items, check if they're higher than 2 and add it to $arr, if so.

**Number 2:**

```
$arr = array();
foreach ($arr2 => $item) {
    if ($item > 2) {
        $arr[] = $item;
    }
}
```

Here you are also iterating over all $arr2 items, checking if they're higher than 2 and adding it to $arr. It's basically how `array_filter` was implemented.

The great difference here is: php's compiled libraries access the data structures much faster than your interpreted code, even if it's bytecode cached. Go ahead and run some tests. Calling `array_filter` once is faster than opening each individual item in-code.

Keep in mind those are only didatic examples, I'm not suggesting you filter your arrays by iterating through every item. I only used those examples to show that accessing data structures in PHP can be somewhat slower than having your components access them for you (in this case, mysql). That alone represents some performance gain.

When you filter something in your MySQL clause, you're not iterating through every table row and excluding those you don't want, like we did before. But that you already know, I'm only repeating what you said.

The same is valid for sorting, cutting and counting your resultset. MySQL will probably access your data structures faster than you in your code.

The optimal result here (that will vary slightly with the size of your resultset, but I'd consider it can grow, or else you wouldn't want pagination) is to leave that to MySQL.

But running two queries may also not be the optimal result. If you could concatenate both queries (using a `UNION` clause, maybe), it would save you some overhead. It's ugly, yes, but *in theory* it should run faster (even though it may be indistinguishable, since PHP is quite efficient communicating with MySQL). You'd sacrifice much readability for an imperceptible performance gain.

**TL;DR:** I'd go for the first option you gave, running two queries.

Answer (score 1):

I would think returning full result sets, and then counting them in PHP, would be a really bad idea.  If you need to display the full count to the end user (i.e. page X of Y), then just get the record count using a database query and then execute the query to get your paginated data.